# Landscape mode creating issues in app

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I had an application of timer and my app should always be in landscape mode. In manifest, I had used:

```
<activity android:name=".MActivity"                      
  android:label="@string/app_name"           
  android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

But sometimes, when I switch from background to foreground, it first appears in portrait mode and then resizes to landscape mode. What's happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the same situation if you paste this line in every of your activities (in the onCreate):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: yes mthpvg, initially i had put this line in my app. Even after that my app was showing same bheaviour. Also it creates lots of issues regarding the functionality of my app. So, I had removed it.

Comment: In your Activity, do you have onPause and onResume with your webView ?

Comment: Well, I invited you to read this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html, because onPause and OnResume are made to manage the event like locking your phone or whenever your app is going background because a tierce app or system event pops up.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"` not the orientation for this attribute

Comment: Thanks pinki for your response. I will chesk this and update you soon.

Comment: now what's happening is, whenever I am locking my phone after unlocking, my app is being destroyed and i have to restart it again. I think,  am not handling onConfigChanged()..so it's starting again. But how to handle that event?

Comment: Actually, I am using a webview in my screen. Only tht webview is shrinking.